# Site footer not showing on SF or SU, OK on SO

Tags: bug, status-completed

Not sure if this is an intended change but the footer on SU and SF have "lost" the links to the other sites (SO shown for comparison). Is this done on purpose or down to the number of sites that are appearing in the footer?

EDIT 15:23pm GMT I've also noticed that the "blog" in each footer always points to blog.stackoverflow.com, rather than the per-site blog (unless I've gone mad and they've all been merged, which would be useful nevertheless)

Windows 7 Enterprise, 32-bit, IE8.

[image: i.imgur.com]

Comment: Note that SF's blog link does indeed link to the SF blog, so I believe the issue is really just the missing site list.

Comment: Server Fault is the only place with its own blog, and it's still linked from there. Everywhere else just has the Stack Overflow blog.

Comment: @Grace Ok, wasn't sure which sites had blogs and not.

Comment: There's *some* Super User blog though, but given the domain name I guess that's not official? http://superuser.blogoverflow.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now fixed - thanks for reporting it!